# Struggling to Make Twilio Media Streams Work with Socket.io: Need Help Event Handling

Tags: node.js, websocket, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have some doubts regarding Twilio Media Stream integration. I am currently working on building a communication application using Nest.js with socket.io that can make calls from my application to a regular phone number. During my research on the web, I came across a solution that suggests using a combination of Twilio Media Streams and Twilio Voice to achieve my goal. However, I have encountered some challenges in the process.

In this scenario, when User A, who uses my application, initiates a call to User B's regular phone number, my application utilizes Twilio APIs to establish the phone call and simultaneously provides a URL to initiate the streaming process.

The actual problem arises from the fact that Twilio doesn't support socket.io, which my app utilizes. Consequently, I don't receive any events from Twilio. To address this issue, I decided to create a separate Node.js application that employs websockets instead of socket.io. This enables me to receive events.

However, a new issue has surfaced. When a user initiates a call, I receive a call SSID, but this SSID is not included in the events emitted by Twilio through websockets. Instead, Twilio emits a stream SSID, which is not present in the backend of the call-initiating app. As a result, I'm unable to determine which stream corresponds to each user's call.

Moreover, since multiple users can use the app and make calls simultaneously, the challenge becomes even more complex. I'm currently seeking a more effective approach to achieving my goal.

I'd like to provide you with relevant code excerpts from both my first and second applications.

**FIRST APP: Initiating Call**

```
  public async makeCall(to: string, from: string): Promise<TwilioCallResponse> {
/**
 * This function hits when the user initiates call from my application
 */
try {
  const call = await this.twilioClient.calls.create({
    twiml: `<Response>
    
    <Pause length="10000"/>
    
    </Response>`,
    url: `https://${this.DOMAIN_URL}/twilio-media-stream/startStream`,
    statusCallback:`https://${this.DOMAIN_URL}/twilio-media-stream/status`,
    statusCallbackEvent: ['initiated', 'answered','completed','ringing'],
    statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
    to: to,
    
    from: from,
  });
  return TwilioCallResponse.of(true, call.sid);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
  return TwilioCallResponse.of(false, '', error.message);
}
}
```

**FIRST APP: Listening for Callback to start streaming**

```
  public async startStream(res:Response,body:TwilioStatusCallbackRequest){
//  This function is called when the call is answered. So we can start stream here.

const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

// In this functions context we get access to call SSID, Since twilio sends that via the callback
const callSid=body.CallSid

  twiml.start().stream({ url: `wss://old-rings-trade.loca.lt` }); 
  twiml.say('Hello, this call will be transcribed.');
  twiml.pause({ length: 60000 }); 
  console.log(twiml.toString())
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
  return res.end(twiml.toString());

  }
```

**SECOND APP: Catching events from twilio media streams and Do some stuff with that**

```
wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
 console.log("New Connection Initiated");

 ws.on("message", function incoming(message) {
   const msg = JSON.parse(message);

    //here the event doesnt have callSSID. So that i cant determine the event is for which call.
  switch (msg.event) {

    case "connected":
         //i'll do some stuff
    
 
    break;
  case "start":
  
        //i'll do some stuff
    break;
  case "media":
  
         //i'll do some stuff
    break;
  case "stop":
        //i'll do some stuff
    break;
  }
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Technical Support Engineer here. As you correctly alluded to, our Media Streams product doesn't support the socket.io protocol, we use raw websockets. In terms of the Call SID being missing, we send this in the [Start Message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream#message-start) as `start.callSid` alongside the `start.streamSid` that you are already seeing.